# Did Taíno natives ever work Spanish galleons?

Tags: naval, 16th-century, spanish-empire, new-world

Did [Taíno](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ta%C3%ADno) natives work as slaves or sailors on 16th-century Spanish ships in early to mid-sixteenth century?

Comment: Are you asking if this ever happened or if this was commonplace? Also you may want to clarify what you mean by "work" on a ship. Would being a personal servant to a ship's officer count or do you mean as a general member of the ship's crew?

Comment: Commonplace as either as sailors or servants.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

I've checked the Spanish primary sources and according to Alonso Peña Montenegro (1596-1688), *Itinerario paraparochos*, the Taínos were employed as *carenadores* (repairers of the hull), taking them in the ships.

Because he talks about those *indios* at the same time as other sailors, probably they weren't slaves.

Comment: ....'repairers of the hull' -- does this mean they worked on re-caulking while ship was beached or worked to repair from inside while ship was underway - like storm damage for example?

Comment: He didn't add more details but the verb _carenar_ usually means reparations made when the ship is beached.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Careening